# Finding the inflection point in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, curve

I have a two column DataFrame with just a list of numbers in x and then a monotonically decreasing -but not constant- set of numbers in column y

```
data

    x        y
0   1   600.000000
1   2   222.361705
2   3   139.820496
3   4   114.353763
4   5   90.807283
5   6   80.022188
6   7   72.193116
7   8   62.309712
8   9   55.362476
9   10  47.335051
10  11  42.821741
11  12  40.540734
12  13  37.758571
```

What I'd like to try is find for what x value is the inflection point in y. I've tried a few different methods of people asking similar but not quite the same question, but they're not quite working.

```
dy = np.diff(data.y) 
idx_max_dy = np.argmax(dy)
```

But I know that's not right, and I'm running into dimensionallity problems. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: do you mean to say that the idx_max_dy is the point on the curve but not necessarily the point in your discrete dataset? If so, you would need to assess the closest match on the df that differs the least from the value obtained.

Comment: Well, I'm not using it correctly. But, basically looking for the point of the greatest change in y. Basically where the slope of y changes the most and finding the corresponding x value. Sorry for the confusion. I've also tried np.gradient

Comment: A simple but less confusing way (since x seems to be evenly spaced out) would be to take y externally in a list, shift the indices by 1 (handle edges appropriately) and assign it as a new column y_shifted. What you now need to do is get max(y-y_shifted) and the row number that corresponds to it.